# In directus, how to access soft deleted items?

Tags: directus

In DirecutsCMS(Directus.io) you could have a status marked as `soft_delete:true` according https://docs.directus.io/guides/status.html#status-mapping.
This removes the item from UI and API, but according do documentation above,

> Only Admin users have access to soft-deleted items

But I can't seem to figure out how. I'm logged in as admin and not able to find the items.

Answer (score 0):

This is true through the API (admins have no restrictions) but I don't believe there is a way to see these in the App yet. Though the development lead (Rijk van Zanten) says this can be done through permissions:

https://github.com/directus/app/issues/174

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear.  As an admin I couldn't see the soft deleted item in the APP or API. I'm at version 7.1.0

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's actually not implemented yet?